# Pride and joy as a plural

Tags: grammar, expressions, nouns, grammatical-number, compounds

I just came across some text in a book which stated, “it was one of his prides and joys“.  That sounds wrong to me. It seems as if it should be pride and joys,  since that phrase is considered a package deal, rather than two separate things. What would be the correct usage in this case?

Comment: What "book"?? The idiom is: pride and joy. "X is my pride and joy".

Comment: @JohnLawler I care as I am tracking the English language and a lot of self-published stuff has interesting data.

Comment: There's gonna be vast individual variation; as @Spankyd says, _pride and joy_ is a package deal, but that doesn't happen instantaneously for everyone. If the phrase is rare enough in such a context, most speakers won't have a ready-made rule and will have to patch one they already have. But everybody doesn't have the same rule; and even if they do by coincidence, they may well not patch it the same way.

Comment: Is *pride and joy* being used as a single concept, or are *pride* and *joy* two separate things joined with a simple conjunction? Context would determine which would make more sense in the plural, although I've never actually heard of *pride and joy* refer to the conjunction of two different things before. In order for it not to sound *odd* I would have rephrased it: *it was one of his prides and one of his joys*.

Comment: At some level, this question is about whether "pride and joy" can function as a plural at all. Some pairings obviously make no sense in plural form—for example, "one and only" in the sentence "You are my one and only"; the sentence "they are my ones and onlies" doesn't work because it contradicts the idea inherent in the original (singular) version of the phrase. So to make sense of the question posed here, you'd first have to decide whether a person can have more than one "pride and joy" or whether the phrase implies a unique and unsharable status for the entity so designated.

Comment: ... Perhaps a more closely comparable phrase "to "pride and joy" than "one and only" is "love of [one's] life": At one level, "She was one of the loves of his life" makes literal sense—he loved multiple people during his life, and she was one of them. But on another level, the point of the phrase "love of [one's] life" is to indicate a nonpareil status, and you can't make the phrase plural without demolishing that sense of the phrase.

Comment: It was his gin and tonic. It was one of his gin and tonics. It was his pride and joy. It was one of his pride and joys.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pride%20and%20joy) has the example *Our children are our pride and joy.* Whatever ***it*** was in the question, it was his pride and joy.